# How to manage chained AJAX calls with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, callback, promise

I have this website that connects with a local service that manages a CardReader with a PIN Pad. There are many different operations that can be completed using this device. Heres an example of one of them:

1. Lock the device
2. Ask for PIN number
3. Release device

Before I used to chain the callbacks between each other, but now, because there are new operations, that also use methods like "lock" and "release", I need to change my code, so that the code for step 1 and 3 is reusable.

I have been trying to solve this with jQuery promises, but Im quite new to this, and I still havent really figured out how they work. Can someone give me a hand?

This is an example of the code im using now. I have removed the business logic from inside the functions, to simplify the example:

```
var CardReader = {

    ////////////////////
    // Different possible messages to the Card Reader
    ////////////////////

    lockDevice: function() {
        this.makeAjaxCall("GET", "/LockDevice", this.lockDeviceCallback);
    },

    getPin: function() {
        this.makeAjaxCall("POST", "/getPin", this.getPinCallback);
    },

    releaseDevice: function() {
        this.makeAjaxCall("POST", "/Release", this.releaseDeviceCallback);
    },

    //////////////////
    // Callbacks for each message to the Card Reader
    //////////////////

    lockDeviceCallback: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        if (textStatus !== "success") { return; }
        this.getCardLogin();
    },

    getCardLoginCallback: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        if (textStatus !== "success") { return; }
        this.releaseDevice();
    },

    releaseDeviceCallback: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        if (textStatus !== "success") { return; }
        //End
    },

    ////////////////
    // Other methods
    ////////////////

    init: function() {
        // UI BIndings
        $(#button).on("click", this.logIn.bind(this));
    },

    logIn: function() {
        this.lockDevice();
    },

    makeAjaxCall: function(callType,  resource, callbackMethod) {

        $.ajax({
            type       : callType,
            url        : "http://localhost:1337" + resource,
            cache      : false,
            dataType   : "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            context    : this,
            complete   : callbackMethod
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could fit your needs even i'm not sure to understand fully your problematic here.

The important point here seems to keep order on ajax method callbacks. You could do something like that:

Create these methods:

```
 _nextCall: function (deferreds, method) {
        if (deferreds.length) this._when(deferreds, method);
        else console.log(method + " SUCCESS");
    },
    _when: function (calls, method) {
        var $promise = $.when(this[calls[0]]())
        $promise.then(function () {
            calls.splice(0, 1);
            this._nextCall(calls, method);
        }, function () {
            console.log(method + " FAILED on: " + calls[0]);
        });
    },
```

Use it like that e.g:

```
logIn: function logIn() {
        var calls = ["lockDevice", "getCardLogin", "releaseDevice"];
        this._when(calls, arguments.callee.name);
    },
    getPinOnly: function getPinOnly() {
        var calls = ["getPin"];
        this._when(calls, arguments.callee.name);
    },
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7x5bw/)

COMPLETE CODE:

```
var CardReader = {

    ////////////////////
    // Different possible messages to the Card Reader
    ////////////////////

    lockDevice: function () {
        return this.makeAjaxCall("GET", "/LockDevice", this.lockDeviceCallback);
    },
    getCardLogin: function () {
        return this.makeAjaxCall("POST", "/getCardLogin", this.getCardLoginCallback);
    },
    getPin: function () {
        return this.makeAjaxCall("POST", "/getPin", this.getPinCallback);
    },

    releaseDevice: function () {
        return this.makeAjaxCall("POST", "/Release", this.releaseDeviceCallback);
    },

    //////////////////
    // Callbacks for each message to the Card Reader
    //////////////////

    lockDeviceCallback: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log("lockDeviceCallback");
        if (textStatus !== "success") {
            return;
        }
    },

    getCardLoginCallback: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log("getCardLoginCallback");
        if (textStatus !== "success") {
            return;
        }
    },
    getPinCallback: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log("getPinCallback");
        if (textStatus !== "success") {
            return;
        }
    },

    releaseDeviceCallback: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log("releaseDeviceCallback");
        if (textStatus !== "success") {
            return;
        }
        //End
    },

    ////////////////
    // Other methods
    ////////////////

    init: function () {
        // UI BIndings
        $('#btn_login').on("click", $.proxy(this.logIn, this));
        $('#btn_getPinCallback').on("click", $.proxy(this.getPinOnly, this));
    },
    _nextCall: function (deferreds, method) {
        if (deferreds.length) this._when(deferreds, method);
        else console.log(method + " SUCCESS");
    },
    _when: function (calls, method) {
        var $promise = $.when(this[calls[0]]())
        $promise.then(function () {
            calls.splice(0, 1);
            this._nextCall(calls, method);
        }, function () {
            console.log(method + " FAILED on: " + calls[0]);
        });
    },
    logIn: function logIn() {
        var calls = ["lockDevice", "getCardLogin", "releaseDevice"];
        this._when(calls, arguments.callee.name);
    },
    getPinOnly: function getPinOnly() {
        var calls = ["getPin"];
        this._when(calls, arguments.callee.name);
    },

    makeAjaxCall: function (callType, resource, callbackMethod) {

        return $.ajax({
            type: callType,
            url: "/echo/json", // + resource,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            context: this,
            success: callbackMethod
        });
    }
};

CardReader.init();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a more fully featured promises library. Take a look at: https://github.com/kriskowal/q
It is well worth taking a little time to understand as it vastly improves the style and readability of your code. Basically you can write each business function so it returns a promise, so something like the following:-

```
function myBusinessFunction(params) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    ....
    doSomeAsyncFunction(params,function(error,result) {
        if (error) {
           deferred.reject(new Error(error)); //pass the error on
        } else {
           deferred.resolve(result);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

So what is going on here is for each async operation that you do create a function, inside that create a deferred and return it. As soon as you get a timeout or an error or any result then you call deferred.reject or deferred.resolve.

With that addition to your code you can then avoid callback hell where you have lots of nested functions and create your overall algorithm code something like the following:-

```
Q.fcall(promisedStep1)
.then(promisedStep2)
.then(promisedStep3)
.then(promisedStep4)
.then(function (value4) {
    // Do something with value4
})
.catch(function (error) {
    // Handle any error from all above steps
})
.done();
```

This closely resembles the try ... catch procedural style programming that is so familiar but you are actually dealing with async processes. When you call the reject on the promise then control flow will pass to the catch function greatly simplifying programming.

There are many additional functions and features in the library so you will be able to cope with running steps in parallel and so on. Checkout the docs it is well worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Read this jquery documentation pages:

http://api.jquery.com/category/callbacks-object/

http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Answer (score 1):

Try `async: false` with your Ajax call. This first completes you Ajax call, and then executes other statements.

makeAjaxCall: function(callType,  resource, callbackMethod) {

```
    $.ajax({
        type       : callType,
        url        : "http://localhost:1337" + resource,
        cache      : false,
        dataType   : "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        context    : this,
        async :false,
        complete   : callbackMethod
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
       jQuery.support.cors = true;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "json",               
            async :false,
            url: "http://yourHost:portnumeber/ServiceName/LockDevice",
            success:
        lockDeviceCallback,
            error:
        function (XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            errorHandler(XMLHttpRequest);
        }
        });
```